# Pointer trouble in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference

I just started learning C coming from a Java background. I am having trouble with a few lines in my code. I am trying to copy what I have seen in other threads, but frankly it still gives errors.

Anyway, I am just trying to pass these structs by reference, but I am getting these four errors.

[image: Errors]

```
printCard(&shuttleArray[i][j]);   // Line 183
```

where printCard()'s header looks like this:

```
void printCard(struct Card* card)
```

Then

```
struct Card shuttleArray[14][4];
initMapping(&shuttleArray);   // Line 199
initMapping(&mapping);   // Line 343
```

Where initMapping()'s header is

```
void initMapping(struct Card* array[14][4])
```

And lastly line 229

```
printSpaceShuttleWithoutWings(&shuttleArray, shuttleCount);   // Line 229
```

Where its header is

```
void printSpaceShuttleWithoutWings(struct Card* shuttleArray[14][4], int shuttleCount)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read what the error messages are telling you, and solve the problems they are describing.

Comment: There is no such thing  in c, you can't pass anything by reference because that does not exists in the c language, you are passing a pointer pointing to the address of the parameter which you obtain by means of the **address of** operator `&`. It's always really dificult for programmers comming from languages like Java to understand these things, that's why when someone asks me, _What language should I learn first?_ I answer -> c.

Comment: @Robert, now if I was able to interpret those, I wouldn't be posting on here now would I... You're help is insurmountably useful.

Comment: `printCard()` expects `struct Card*` but you are passing `struct Card **`

Comment: @Milind, that worked for that one. Any idea why the others are acting up? They seem to be the same, but it didn't work.

Comment: In C passing an array will actually pass a pointer to that array. As such, the calls to initMapping and printSpaceShuttleWithoutWings should be without the &, and the declarations of these functions should go without * -- which will result in passing the arrays around by reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
void initMapping(struct Card* array[14][4])
```

declares a function that takes a two-dimensional array of pointers to `struct Card`.

```
struct Card shuttleArray[14][4];
```

is not an array of pointers to `struct Card`, so shoving it into that parameter slot is not possible. The same applies to `printSpaceShuttleWithoutWings`, and inside `printSpaceShuttleWithoutWings`, where `shuttleArray` is declared as array of pointers,

```
printCard(&shuttleArray[i][j]);
```

attempts to shove a `struct Card**` into a `struct Card*` parameter.

The sanest way to resolve this, I think, would be to write

```
void initMapping(struct Card array[14][4]);
// or, equivalently, one of
//
// void initMapping(struct Card array[][4]);
// void initMapping(struct Card (*array)[4]);
//
// The same needs to be done for printSpaceShuttleWithoutWings.

...

initMapping(shuttleArray);
```

This declares that `array` shall be a pointer<sup>1</sup> to one-dimensional arrays of four `struct Card`s each, and `shuttleArray` is, in the function call, decayed to a pointer to its first subarray. `array[i]` is then the `i`th subarray of the `shuttleArray`, and the expressions `array[i][j]` and `&array[i][j]` work as you'd expect.

<sup>1</sup>In function parameter declarations, the array syntax is for legibility; the declared parameter is still a pointer. An outer array extent, if given, is silently ignored.

**Side note:** It would have been possible to make the call

```
initMapping(&shuttleArray)
```

compile by declaring `initMapping` as

```
void initMapping(struct Card (*array)[14][4]);
```

...which declares `array` to be a pointer to a two-dimensional array of `struct Card`s. However, doing so would make using it inside the function more cumbersome; where with the above code you can write `array[i][j]`, you would have to write `(*array)[i][j]` with this.

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing this with typedef. Add following line to your code and then refer `arr` instead.

```
 typedef struct Card arr[14][4];
```

and then declare the functions like below

```
 void printCard(arr *array)
 void initMapping(arr *array)
 void printSpaceShuttleWithoutWings(arr *shuttleArray, int shuttleCount)
```